# I need help adding Variables/Strings to an Equation

Tags: python

I am trying to make a code that can calculate Pythagoras Theorem formulas for me, but I am having trouble adding the answers from my 'raw_input()'s into an equation to add them together. I'm doing something wrong but i'm not quite sure what... PLEASE HELP!

```
need = raw_input("What do you need to Use?")

if need == "pythagoras" or "Pythagoras":
    pythagoras = raw_input("What side do you Need?")

if pythagoras == "hypotenuse" or "Hypotenuse":
    k1 = raw_input("Known Side 1")
    k2 = raw_input("Known Side 2")
    print eval('str(k1) + str(k2)')
```

Comment: What have you tried? You should always include sample code where you have some so we can see where you're going wrong.

Comment: Please post your current code, we are not clairvoyants

Comment: Usually it's an error on line 3, in my experience.

Comment: iv'e added my code so far

Comment: This is wrong on so many ... lines

Comment: `need == "pythagoras" or "Pythagoras"` does *not* do what you think it does. Programming languages need you to be more specific than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of problems:

- `or` isn't working as you expect it to be. In python, you need to say `if need == "pythagoras" or need == 'Pythagoras'`. This is the same for your second if-statement.
- Using `eval()` [is a **bad** idea](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html). Your result can easily be obtained without it:

  ```
  str(k1) + str(k2)
  ```

However, `raw_input()` returns a *string*, which (I'm presuming) you want to convert into an integer. You can do this with the [`int()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) function:

```
k1 = int(raw_input("Known Side 1"))
k2 = int(raw_input("Known Side 2"))
```

Now the input will be an integer and not a string.

Also, you can simply just do `if need.lower() == 'pythagoras'` and `if pythagoras.lower() == 'hypotenuse'` for your if-statements.

Comment: @RossGibson Actually, looking at your code, my previous solution was not 100% correct

Comment: sory, im having trouble finding out where i need to use this 'int()' stuff.

Comment: @RossGibson When you put in an input for `raw_input()`, the result is a string. If you do `'34' + '36'`, you get `'3436'`, because they are strings, and that is what strings do when you attempt to add them. To actually get a result of `70` (34 + 36), you need to convert the strings to integers, and then you can do `34 + 36`. To do this, you can use the `int()` function

Comment: thank you so much Haidro! it completely fixed it!

Comment: just one last thing, both integer's need to be squared to work out the equation... how do i do this?

Comment: iv'e tried: print int(k1**) + int(k2**) and print int(k1)** + int(k2)** but i cant figure it out

Comment: @RossGibson To square a number, use `**`. `4**2` is four squared (16)

Comment: aaah... well, i feel kinda dumb that i didnt remember that... thanks again!

Comment: so sorry to be bothering you... but i need one LAST thing, to complete the equation i need to square root the answer, iv'e got it all set out but i don't know how to use the square root function in python.                                                                          i know its wrong but this is what i have for the square roots:                     print sqrt(int(k1)**2 + int(k2)**2)

Comment: @RossGibson The square root of a number is the same as `n**0.5`. I'd talk maths here, but this is about programming

Comment: ok thanks, ill try and figure it out

Answer (score 2):

You should use `int()` or `float()` to convert the input numbers from the user to integers/floats and then apply the formula to them.

`need == "pythagoras" or "Pythagoras"` is equivalent to :

`(need == "pythagoras") or "Pythagoras"` so if `need` equals `"pythagoras"` then this returns `True` else return `"Pythagoras"`(i.e a True value), in other words your `if` conditions are always `True` no matter what the input is.

Working code:

```
need = raw_input("What do you need to Use?")
#use a while loop loop, this will continuously ask for the user input
#until he doesn't enters a corrects one.
while need.lower() != "pythagoras":  
    print "Invalid choice! try again"
    need = raw_input("What do you need to Use?")

pythagoras = raw_input("What side do you Need?")

if pythagoras.lower() == "hypotenuse":
    k1 = int(raw_input("Known Side 1: ")) #use int() to convert the user input to integers
    k2 = int(raw_input("Known Side 2: ")) # use float() if you want floats
    print (k1**2 + k2**2)**0.5            # now apply the formula
```

Comment: `need.lower() == "hypotenuse"` would be better. Also `need.lower() != "pythagoras"`

Comment: @AnkurAnkan good point, fixed that.